# React Router con parámetros opcionales

Tags: reactjs, router

Resulta que estoy haciendo un proyecto en React en la cual tengo definida las siguientes rutas:

```
state = {
    routes: [
      {
        path: "/jefatura/negocios",
        component: VisualizarNegocios
      },
      {
        path: "/jefatura/negocios/:id_empresa",
        component: DetallesNegocio
      }
    ]
  };
```

Lo anterior es un array de objeto que contiene las rutas que creo y que después se colocan de este modo:

```
&lt;Switch&gt;
    {this.state.routes.map((route, i) =&gt; (
      &lt;Route key={i} path={route.path} render={() =&gt; &lt;route.component /&gt;} /&gt;
    ))}
  &lt;/Switch&gt;
```

El problema sucede cuando intento navegar entre rutas, ya que prácticamente es la misma ruta solo que se le pasa un parámetro adicional en la segunda que tiene un parámetro `id_empresa` pero que llama distintos componentes, sin embargo, me sigue mostrando el mismo componente de la ruta que no tiene el parámetro, que hacer en este caso para que dependiendo si le pasa o no el parámetro muestre un componente u otro

Comment: Te sugiero que revises la documentación de [React Router](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/philosophy)

Comment: ya la he revisado, y por eso pregunto aca por que no encuentro solucion

Comment: mmm revisa la respuesta que te deje a ver si te sirve...

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar `match.params` para recuperar los valores o parametros que le pasas a tus rutas en tus componentes, mira a continuación te dejo un ejemplo. Si quieres saber más te sugiero que revises la documentación de [React Router](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/philosophy)

```
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";

function Child({ match }) {

  if (match.params.id === "mi_ruta") {
    return (
      <div>
        <h3>ID: {match.params.id} mi ruta es igual</h3>
      </div>
    )
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <h3>ID: {match.params.id} mi ruta es diferente por eso aparesco yo :p</h3>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Añade la prop `exact` a las rutas para evitar que se rendericen varias a la vez.

Te pongo un ejemplo:

```
     state = {
        routes: [
          {
            path: "/jefatura/negocios",
            component: VisualizarNegocios,
            exact: true
          },
          {
            path: "/jefatura/negocios/:id_empresa",
            component: DetallesNegocio,
            exact: true
          }
        ]
      };
```

y en el componente:

```
  <Switch>
    {this.state.routes.map((route, i) => (
      <Route key={i} exact={route.exact} path={route.path} render={() => <route.component />} />
    ))}
  </Switch>
```